# In Outlook, how can I select all messages and move them to a folder with one click?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation

I love the customizable "Quick Actions" at the top and I've set some up to move things to various folders or convert messages to appointments, etc. One thing I still can't figure out how to do, though, is have a button that will select all messages in a folder, and move them to another specified (preconfigured) folder.

Basically, from my inbox, I want a single button to move all my mail into another folder for me, without having to hit Ctrl+A to select them all first.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible; you'll need to write a macro to do it though.

From "[Writing an Outlook Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa209971(v=office.11).aspx)":

> A macro is any public subroutine in a code module. A function or a private subroutine cannot be a macro, and a macro cannot be located in a class or form module.
>
> To create a new macro
>
> 1. In Outlook, point to Macro on the Tools menu, and then click Visual Basic Editor.
> 2. In the Project window, double-click the module you want to contain the macro.
> 3. On the Insert menu, click Procedure.
> 4. In the Name box, type a name for the macro. The name cannot contain spaces.
> 5. Click OK. (The template for the macro subroutine appears in the code module window).
> 6. Type the code you want to run in the body of the subroutine.

Here's some example (untested) code to get you started:

```
Sub MoveItems() 

  Dim Messages As Selection 
  Dim Msg As MailItem 
  Dim NS As NameSpace 

  Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set Messages = ActiveExplorer.Selection 

  If Messages.Count = 0 Then 
    Exit Sub 
  End If 

  For Each Msg In Messages 
    Msg.Move NS.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("SavedMail") 
  Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: With a little tweaking, and [learning about Macros in Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736.aspx), I got this working. Thank you!

Comment: @SpikeX -- Can you post your finished code with the tweaks you made? I'd like to do this as well. Thanks.

Comment: My code has company-specific information in it that I can't share. The example here provides a good enough example of what needs to be done, you just need to tailor it to your specific folder/account names.